# Как отправить ссылку по другому

Tags: html, html5

Я хочу сделать ссылку на странице. И отправить на почту. Чтобы она не попала в спам

`<BASE href=“https://google.com”><href a=“www.google.com”>click</a>`

Я делаю так. По другому как можно?

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что у вас сам тег записан неверно. Правильно **base** т.е. с маленьких букв. Также обязательно понимать, что данная конструкция должна быть записана в тег **head**, а теге **head** абсолютно никак не может быть каких-либо ссылок.

```html
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тег BASE</title>
  <base target="_blank"> 
 </head>
```

Самая же главная причина почему вы не можете выполнить поставленную задачу, так это потому что base **для этого не предназначен!** Подробную документацию можно найти здесь: [Base](https://webref.ru/html/base), [Ссылки](https://webref.ru/html/a).

Comment: Я решал похожую проблему при помощи JS (javascript) и jQuery (библиотека javascript).